# Why is OPENGL missing 16-bit RGB format that is unsigned?

Tags: opengl, textures, glteximage2d

I have been using a 16-bit monochrome texture using the **GL_R16** format. This works just fine.
I am now in need of a 3-channel 16-bit texture.

When examining the manpage [glTexStorage2D](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexStorage2D.xhtml) though, I see that there seems to be a gap in functionality.

One channel is available: **GL_R16**

Two channel is available: **GL_RG16**

Four channel is available: **GL_RGBA16**

But three channels, only comes in SNORM (signed normalized) flavour: **GL_RGB16_SNORM**.

What happened to **GL_RGB16**? Adding a 4th channel seems wasteful, so I would like to avoid that. I also want to avoid dealing with -1..1 samples, as my data is unsigned.

Comment: ``GL_RGB16`` is a 48 bit format, correct? That's not something most hardware supports. Weird that your part supports ``GL_RGB16_SNORM``, but OpenGL drivers aren't required to support them all...

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn: GL spec disagrees

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What happened to `GL_RGB16`?

It's fine. It is an allowed and for textures also a required to be supported format (in contrast to when using such a texture as a framebuffer attachment for render-to-texture), as per table 8.12 in the [OpenGL 4.6 core profile spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf).

Those OpenGL "reference pages" are unfortunately notoriously incomplete, outdated, often misleading and sometimes even flat-out wrong. The only reliable source for documentation is the OpenGL specification.

> Adding a 4th channel seems wasteful, so I would like to avoid that

What hardware does with such a format is another story entirely. For example, any real-world GPU will internally pad `GL_RGB8` to RGBA, because they won't like 3-byte aligned texels. I wouldn't be surprised if they didn't like 6 byte alingments for `GL_RGB16` either.